# How to find the minimum sum of range of k partitions of an array of size n?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming

There is an array A of size n. We are given the number of partitions k. How to find the minimum sum of range of all partitions?
Range is difference between maximum and mimimum element in that partition.
For eg. A={20, 30, 40, 41, 45}, k = 4. The minimum possible sum of range of all partitions is 1.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific programming language?

Comment: Preferably C++ or Java but algorithm would be fine.

Comment: Is array always sorted?

Comment: No, array is not always sorted.

Comment: Do the elements in a partition have to be contiguous?

Comment: No. They need not be contiguous.