# Arrange n items in k nonempty groups such that the difference between the minimum element and the maximum element of each group is minimized

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Given *N* items with values `x[1], ..., x[n]` and an integer *K* find a linear time algorithm to arrange these *N* items in *K* non empty groups such that in each group the range (difference between minimum and maximum element values/keys in each group) is minimized and therefore the sum of the ranges is minimum.

For example given `N=4`, `K=2` and the elements `1 1 4 3` the minimum range is `1` for groups `(1,1)` and `(4,3)`.

Comment: Range of parameters.

Comment: what happens if you sort them? what happen if n%k is not 0? can a group be smaller then k?

Comment: The group must be non-empty. Which means that it will have >=1 element

Comment: what's the maximum range of `n`?

Comment: k,n <= 10^5  and x_i <= 10^9

Comment: You can minimize ONE thing. "Minimize difference in each group" makes no sense. What's better, two groups with differences 3 and 4 or two groups with differences 2 and 5?

Comment: Do you want to minimize the maximum difference among all groups or the sum of their differences? It is not the same thing. And do you really need a linear solution or O(N log N) would be fine, too?

Comment: this is a [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188492/how-to-find-the-minimum-sum-of-range-of-k-partitions-of-an-array-of-size-n

Comment: can you please answer this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63417793/divide-n-items-given-in-an-integer-array-in-k-groups-where-k-should-be-minimum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can binary search the answer.
Assume the optimal answer is *x*. Now you should verify whether we can group the items into *k* groups where the maximum difference between the group items is at most *x*. This can be done in *O(n)* [after sorting the array]. Traverse the sorted array and pick consecutive items until the difference between minimum number you have picked for this group and the maximum number you have picked hasn't exceeded *x*. After that you should initialize a new group and repeat this process. At the end count how many groups you have made. If the number of groups is more than *k* we can conclude that we can not group the items in *k* groups with *x* being the answer. So we should increase *x*. By binary searching on *x* we can find the minimum *x*.

The overall complexity is *O(NlogN)*.

Here is a sample implementation in C++

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 4, k = 2;
    std::vector<int> v = {1, 1, 4, 3};
    sort(v.begin(), v.end());

    int low = 0, high = *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());

    while ( low < high ){
        int x = (low+high)/2;

        int groups = 0;
        int left = 0;
        while (left < v.size()){
            int right = left;
            while( right < v.size() && v[right] - v[left] <= x ){
                ++right;
            }
            ++groups;
            left = right;
        }
        // printf("x:%d groups:%d\n", x, groups );
        if (groups > k)
        {
            low = x + 1;
        } else {
            high = x;
        }
    }

    cout << "result is " << low << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I'll assume that we want to minimize the sum of differences over all groups.

1. Let's sort the numbers. There's an optimal answer where each group is a consecutive segment in the sorted array (proof: let A1 < B1 < A2 < B2. We can exchange A2 and B1. The answer will not increase).
2. Let a[l], a[l + 1], ..., a[r] is a group. It's cost is `a[r] - a[l] = (a[r] - a[r - 1]) + (a[r - 1] - a[r - 2]) + ... + (a[l + 1] - a[l])`. It leads us to a key insight: `k` groups is `k - 1` gaps and the answer is `a[n - 1] - a[0] - sum of gaps`. Thus, we just need to maximize the gaps.
3. Here is a final solution:

   - sort the array
   - compute differences between adjacent numbers
   - take `k - 1` largest differences. That's exactly where the groups split.
   - We can find the `k-1`th largest  element in linear time (or if we are fine with `O(N log N)` time, we can just sort them). That's it.

Here is an example:

`x = [1, 1, 4, 3], k = 2` 
sorted: `[1, 1, 3, 4]` 
differences: `[0, 2, 1]` 
taking `k - 1 = 1` largest gaps: it's 2. Thus the groups are `[1, 1]` and `[3, 4]`.

A slightly more contrived one:
`x = [8, 2, 0, 3], k = 3` 
sorted: `[0, 2, 3, 8]` 
differences: `[2, 1, 5]` 
taking `k - 1 = 2` largest gaps: they're 2 and 5. Thus, the groups are `[0], [2, 3], [8]` with the total cost of 1.